# Not working modal pop up button in angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, modal-dialog

```
<div class="modal fade" id="getUserDetails" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="getUserDetails">
  <div class="modal-dialog container2" role="document">
    test
  </div>
</div>


<button (click)="getUserDetails(participant.userId)" type="button" class="btn " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#getUserDetails">
  Detail
</button>
```

My angular version 6

bootstrap version 4

**button (click)="getUserDetails(participant.userId)"** is normally working.
But data-target (bound modal fade) is not visible.

I tried to set up JQuery and import JQuery to angular.json.
still it's not works
please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
1) Install bootstrap using npm

npm install bootstrap --save

2) Install JQUERY

npm install jquery --save

open .angular-cli.json this file are available on you angular directory open that file and add the path of bootstrap css, see the below example

"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
           ],

    //than add div for model in your component html like below

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<button  type="button" (click)="getUserDetails()" class="btn " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Detail </button>
```

Comment: you need to add  <div class="modal-content"> and  <div class="modal-body">after <div class="modal-dialog container2" role="document"> like below
<div class="modal-dialog container2" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
     
      <div class="modal-body">
    test
     </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: I guess this problem by conflict between Bootstrap css setting and
my component css file setting
How I set my component setiing ignored Bootstrap css setting

Comment: declare your bootstrap css in angualr.json file than its not conflict with other css

Comment: I use style in https://github.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-6/tree/master/src.
no import node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.
bit if the code is imported in angular.json
result is same...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps carefully. You might have already installed bootstrap, jquery, and required dependencies. Your problem is never the conflict between the component styles and bootstrap. Please try the following and let me know.
you can use 2 clicks for a **`(click)="getUserDetails(participant.userId);basicModal.show()"`**

Step 1

```
npm i angular-bootstrap-md --save
```

Step 2

`import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';` into app.module and

Step 3

```
imports: [
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
],
schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
```

Step 4: Make sure that styleExt is set to "scss" in angular.json file, if not change:

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
```

Step 5: Make sure you have `src/styles.scss`. If you have src/styles.css instead, rename it to `.scss.`

if you want to change styles in existing project you can use `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`

Step 6: add below lines to angular.json:

```
    "styles": [
        "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
        "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
        "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",
        "src/styles.scss"
    ],
    "scripts": [
          .....
    ],
```

Step 7 Put the following basic modal code in your respective markup template and try, you will achieve the modal pop up.

```
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="relative waves-light" (click)="basicModal.show()" mdbWavesEffect>Launch demo modal</button>

<div mdbModal #basicModal="mdbModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myBasicModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" mdbBtn color="secondary" class="waves-light" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()" mdbWavesEffect>Close</button>
        <button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="relative waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

reference is taken from [MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/advanced/modals/#liveDemo)

Answer (score 0):

In my scripts I add

```
 "scripts": [
                        "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                        "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
                        "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
             ]
```